# steps to authenticate the user using SAML SSO to my existing C# web app

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I looked at multiple articles online but nothing was useful, can some one help me with the steps to authenticate the user using SAML SSO to my existing C# web app?

Comment: Currently I have only this information available to me:                                                      -> SAML Single Sign-On Service URL:https://login.microsoftonline.com/##############/saml2
•        SAML Entity ID:https://sts.comity.net/######/
•         Sign-Out URL:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/w#########3n?wa=wsignout1.0

Answer (score 0):

.net doesn't provide native library for SAML authentication. You need to leverage third party SAML library. I recommend [Sustainsys](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/index.html). 
Check the corresponding guideline according to your project type.

I use APS.NET MVC as example:

1, Install "[Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc/)" package

2, Configure web.config file referring to https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/configuration.html

Here is an example for `sustainsys.saml2` section:

```
  <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://www.contoso.org/checkresourceapp[This is your application URI in Azure AD]"
                    returnUrl="http://localhost:54664/[this is the reply url of your app in AAD]"

                    >
    <nameIdPolicy allowCreate="true" format="Persistent"/>

    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://sts.windows.net/<YourADTenantID>/"
          metadataLocation="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<YourADTenantID>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
          loadMetadata = "true"
          allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"
          signOnUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<YourADTenantID>"
          binding="HttpRedirect">

      </add>

    </identityProviders>

    <federations>
      <add metadataLocation="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<YourADTenantID>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = "false" />
    </federations>
  </sustainsys.saml2>
```

3, Add "Authorize" attribute to the page you want to enable authentication

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this but I get the below error:                       
       HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. at                                                                        
        <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://localhost:44300"                                                     Config Error    The configuration section 'sustainsys.saml2' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: Sounds like the issue is caused by misformat of the config file. Could you post the complete config? Remember to remove private information.

Comment: You were right, I fixed the issue in the config file but now I get this error:                           Server Error in '/' Application.
IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. HttpResponseMessage: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]', HttpResponseMessage.Content: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

Comment: I assume this url is for metadata location. Pay attention to:  a) your login.microsoftonline.com url is misformat. It contains special characters like "<" . Please check it again.     b) the url you configured is for openid, not SAML. the correct url should be like https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml   c) you accidently posted your real tenant id, please delete it for security

Comment: I deleted the comment, thanks. I had few references to OpenID, once I deleted this, I get the error: "HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page. sustain sys saml" Am I missing something? Should I be following the same steps as here: https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Samples/SampleMvcApplication

Comment: After trying another method: I get this                                            
       AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'https://sts.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' was not found in the directory 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.         Is it something to do with Azure AD setting? Pls advise

Comment: hmm, it's hard for us to help you with an error message only. I suggested 3 steps. I assume you met problem when configuring web.config. Please strictly follow the Sustainsys official guidance then refer to my web.config sample. If any problem occurs, please post your complete web.config, so that we can help.